# Using async/await with done()/next() middleware functions

Tags: node.js, express, async-await, passport-local

I'm starting to use async/await.  Generally, what is a pattern to use await with middleware done/next functions?

For example, how could I replace .then() in the code below with await?  `localAuthenticate` is done/next middleware.  Do I need to make a separate `async` function to use `await` inside it?

I'd like something like this (even better w/o the try/catch):

```
function localAuthenticate(User, email, password, hostname, done) {
  try { // where is async?
    // Find user
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() }).exec()
    if(!user) return done(null, false, { message: 'This email is not registered.' });
    // Test password
    user.authenticate(password, function(authError, authenticated) {
      if(authError) return done(authError);
      if(!authenticated) return done(null, false, { message: 'This password is not correct.' });
      return done(null, user);
    });
  } catch(err) { done(err); } 
}
```

Original code from Passport.js authentication middleware:

```
function localAuthenticate(User, email, password, hostname, done) {
  User.findOne({
    email: email.toLowerCase()
  }).exec()
    .then(user => {
      if(!user) {
        return done(null, false, {
          message: 'This email is not registered.'
        });
      }
      user.authenticate(password, function(authError, authenticated) {
        if(authError) {
          return done(authError);
        }
        if(!authenticated) {
          return done(null, false, { message: 'This password is not correct.' });
        } else {
          return done(null, user);
        }
      });
    })
    .catch(err => done(err));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` can only be called within an `async` function - see [the MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await)

- Your function needs to be `async function localAuthenticate(User, email, password, hostname, done)`.
- The `try/catch` is the way to catch exceptions when using `await`, instead of the `.then/.catch` you are used to when dealing with Promises directly.

Your function would approximate, when using `async/await`:

```
async function localAuthenticate(User, email, password, hostname, done) {
  try {
    // Find user
    let user = await User.findOne({ email: email.toLowerCase() }).exec()
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'This email is not registered.' })
    }

    user.authenticate(password, function (authError, authenticated) {
      if (authError) {
        return done(authError)
      }

      if (!authenticated) {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'This password is not correct.' });
      }

      return done(null, user);
    })
  } catch (err) {
    done(err)
  }
}
```

Further reading:

- http://rossboucher.com/await/#/
- https://ponyfoo.com/articles/understanding-javascript-async-await

Comment: changing `localAuthenticate` to `async` would return a promise.  Does that affect it as middleware?  I never checked the return values of `done()`

Comment: The middleware won't proceed until you call `next()` - which you should do inside the `try` block.